# Python проблема: После двоеточие пишет invalid syntax и выделяет пустоту, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**На python**

```
print("Змеиный калькуклятор v1.5")
what = input("Что делаем?(+,-,*,/.)")
e = 0
a = float ( input("Введи первое число:") )
b = float ( input("Введи второе число:") )
while e > 0:
    if e == 1:
        break
    if what == "+":
        c = a + b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "-":
        c = a - b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "*":
        c = a * b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "/":
        c = a / b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    else:
        print("Выбрана неверная операция!")

    input ("Нажмите на C и Enter чтобы продолжить, нажмите на E и Enter чтобы выйти"):# Вот здесь выделяет пустоту и говорит SyntaxError: invalid syntax
        if "e":
            e + 1
        else:
            e + 0
```

Comment: Добавлять в вопрос **полный** текст ошибки.

Comment: все равно ничего не сделает, даже когда исправить синтаксическую ошибку. Придется исправлять еще и логическую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите двоеточие после вызова функции `input`:

```py
input ("..."):
#            ^
```

***P.S.:***
Далее в коде Вы не присваиваете никуда результат ввода (а также вычислений `e + 1`, `e + 0`), а условие `if "e"` всегда истинно.

Comment: Еще отступы нужно уменьшить во строках после последнего input

Comment: Я попробовал убрать двоеточие в последнем  `input` и убрал в последнем `if`и `else` табулирование, но в конце не появлялся результат вычисления, т.е. просто вводишь цифры и программа закрывается.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Змеиный калькуклятор v1.5")
e = 1
while e > 0:
    what = input("Что делаем?(+,-,*,/.)")
    a = float ( input("Введи первое число:") )
    b = float ( input("Введи второе число:") )


    if what == "+":
        c = a + b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "-":
        c = a - b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "*":
        c = a * b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    elif what == "/":
        c = a / b
        print("Результат:" + str (c))

    else:
        print("Выбрана неверная операция!")

    input ("Нажмите на C и Enter чтобы продолжить, нажмите на E и Enter чтобы выйти:")
    if "e": break
    elif "c": e + 0
```

Решил проблему!

Comment: Не решили - то что вводится в последний input никак не учитывается, и  всегда будет срабатывать ветка `if "e"`, потому что любая непустая строка эквивалентна истине.